# ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE error Google Chrome—This site can't be reached might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, certificate

Today I encountered `ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE` error:

```
This site can't be reached
The webpage at https://... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE
```

[image]

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Comment: I got exactly same error when self signed SSL is generated from IIS Manager Wizard. I removed it and generated a new SSL Self Signed from Powershell and it works. IIS Wizard is broken when SSL Self Signed is done.

Comment: @yogihosting it worked!!! You should post it as an answer! I am using the certificate for an internal testing server. Why should we spend money to pay for a certificate in this context? Cmd in powershell as administrator: `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName <serverName>.<domain> -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My`. Then I bound the certificate to site (it appeared in the drop down list with certificates on the Bindings dialog)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on the tags you have provided, this SSL error is occurring on the Google Chrome browser and involves [IIS (Internet Information Services)](https://www.iis.net/) and SSL certificates.
The `ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE` error specifically suggests there is a problem with how the SSL certificate is being used or is recognized by Chrome, potentially due to a misconfiguration in IIS or an issue with the certificate itself.

[This thread](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/239508594/err-ssl-key-usage-incompatible-error-in-chrome-but-not-edge-for-all-google-sites-and-some-others?hl=en) reports a similar issue:

> We found a fix. Delete the user's local state file located in `C:\users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State`. After deleting it the issue went away. Let me know if that works for you.
>
> EDIT: Confirmed this is also happening on MacOS. Need to go to `Library/Application Support/Google`/ and Delete the `Local State` file from their as well.

And:

> The root cause of this issue is a Chrome Variation, which you can read more about in the Chrome release notes for versions 115, 116, and 117, available to read in [Google's previous release notes](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/10314655).
>
> Search the notes for "Require X.509 key usage extension for RSA certificates chaining to local roots" to read the blurb Google shared about this change.
>
> There is no flag you can adjust to revert this variation, but Chrome has provided the policy [`RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled`](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled) to temporarily disable this variation while you update your certificates.

---

> Explain exactly what it does and why it won't compromise Chrome's security.

Deleting the `Local State` file in Chrome's User Data directory is a troubleshooting step.

As noted by [Giovanni Esposito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13897065/giovanni-esposito) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77519169/err-ssl-key-usage-incompatible-error-google-chrome-this-site-cant-be-reached-mi/77533590#comment136752905_77533590): "it's just a (terrible) workaround because you need to do that every time"

True. The actual resolution to the ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE error would be to update the SSL certificate with the proper Key Usage extensions, as required by Chrome. Utilizing the `RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled` policy offers only a reprieve, allowing operations to continue while certificates are brought up to standard.

#### What deleting the `Local State` file does:

Chrome runs experiments called 'variations', which are essentially A/B tests for new features or changes. Deleting the `Local State` file resets these variations to their default state.
The `Local State` file holds temporary state information for Chrome, including some settings and states that are not exposed through the standard settings interface.
If the file becomes corrupted, it can cause errors. Deleting it forces Chrome to create a new `Local State` file, which can resolve such errors.

#### Why it will *not* compromise security:

The `Local State` file is not directly linked to your personal browsing data such as history, bookmarks, or saved passwords. It contains information about the state of the browser, but does not store sensitive information like personal identifiers or encryption keys.
And Chrome will regenerate the `Local State` file upon the next launch anyway, restoring the default state without the variations that might be causing issues.

---

And regarding the `RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled`  policy:

> This `RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled`  policy is available for administrators to preview the behavior of a future release, which will enable this check by default. At that point, this policy will remain temporarily available for administrators that need more time to update.
>
> Connections which fail this check will fail with the error `ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE`. Sites which fail with this error likely have a misconfigured certificate.
> Modern ECDHE_RSA cipher suites use the "`digitalSignature`" key usage option, while legacy RSA decryption cipher suites use the "`keyEncipherment`" key usage option. If unsure, administrators should include both in RSA certificates meant for HTTPS.
>
> ```
>    true = Enable RSA key usage checking
>    false = Disable RSA key usage checking
>    not set = Use the default setting for RSA key usage checking
> ```

---

The same thread includes the actual soution:

> We had the same problem, the solution is to create a new self-signed certificate that has or is created with key usage: `"Digital Signature, Certificate Signing, Off-line CRL Signing, CRL Signing (86)"`, after that all our internal sites are working now even in Chrome.
> You should create it with that usage key, and it should be from OpenSSL, v3 version.
>
> [image: https://storage.googleapis.com/support-forums-api/attachment/message-245153877-325753115131158525.png]

For creating a valid certificate with OpenSSL use the following parameters as `keyUsage` - `digitalSignature, keyCertSign, cRLSign`.

Comment: Deleting Loal State solution it's just a (terrible) workaround because you need to do that every time.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Thank you for your feedback, I agree. I have included your comment to make that clear.

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this issue in Edge ?

Comment: @NalinBhatia I have not seen an equivalent for Edge, which is based on Chromium.

Comment: @NalinBhatia Scratch that. [FurryFennec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12860538/furryfennec)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77901976/6309) looks promising. It could work for Edge.

Comment: This might be useful, OpenSSL parameters are keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyCertSign, cRLSign

Comment: @mivra Good point. Can you edit the answer to include that? I can validate your edit.

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent Edge registry setting since Edge 121 now enforces the check is to create a DWORD in:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score -2):

We found a fix... After deleting the "local state", our issue kept coming back. So we narrowed it down to a group policy.

Fix: go to `C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\` and delete all the subfolders and files in this folder (not the root folder just the sub folders)

Then, in CMD run [`gpupdate/ force`](https://ss64.com/nt/gpupdate.html). That's worked for us.